# How to add a array variable parameter in mysql query?(PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do a query like:

```
  UPDATE screening
                 SET maileddate = NOW(),
                     reference = '{$reference[$user_id]}'
                     WHERE user_id IN(....)
```

And I want to do the judgement, when reference[$user_id] is empty, reference[$user_id] = NULL.
My code is :

```
    if(empty($reference[$user_id]) || $reference[$user_id] == ''){
        $reference[$user_id] = NULL;
     }
```

But when I execute the query, if $reference[$user_id] is empty, the value of reference in database is empty but not null. What should I do to make it null? thanks

Comment: The last part is unclear. Could you say it another way?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to pass `NULL` as a string to MySQL if the variable is empty.  Use a different variable to hold the possibly NULL contents and quote the non-null contents.  Don't forget to escape it otherwise:

```
$refid = empty($reference['user_id']) ? "NULL" : "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($reference['user_id']) . "'";

UPDATE screening SET maileddate = NOW(), reference = '{$refid}'
      WHERE user_id IN(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a string saying null. If it's null `$reference[$user_id] = 'null';`

Oh, also with the query you should be using `reference IS null {$reference[$user_id]}` instead of the equals sign

Comment: I got the string value 'null' in database, not NULL

Comment: Ohhh, that changes everything. Then just do the if statement to say if it's null set it to 'null' then keep `reference = {$reference[$user_id]}'

Comment: wait, now I'm confused... do you want to save the string 'null' into the db or save the value NULL into the db?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, my guess is it has something to do with `reference = '{$reference[$user_id]}'` having `{$reference[$user_id]}` in single quotes. MySQL is going to see whatever is in there as what should be in the database. So if `$reference[$user_id]` prints out as nothing (because it's NULL), that bit of your query will be `reference = ''` rather than `reference = NULL`. You need to use the keyword NULL rather than the actual value NULL for the variable you use in the query.

As an example:

```
$query = "UPDATE screening " . 
             "SET maileddate = NOW(), " . 
                 "reference = " . ($reference[$user_id] === NULL ? 'NULL ' : "'{$reference[$user_id]}' ") . 
                 "WHERE user_id IN(....)";
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of what to do?

Comment: Edited my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

```
$reference = 'reference = ';
$reference .= ' empty($reference[$user_id])  ? 'NULL' : "'". mysql_real_escape_string($reference[$user_id]) . "'";

$query = "UPDATE screening
      SET maileddate = NOW(),
      $reference       
      WHERE user_id IN(....)";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$user_id = empty($reference[$user_id]) ? 'NULL' : $reference[$user_id];
$sql = "UPDATE screening
                 SET maileddate = NOW(),
                     reference = " . $user_id . "
                     WHERE user_id IN(....)";
```

Comment: This will set the `reference` column to an empty string rather than NULL